# MU: There 3 super admins but it says there are 5

Tags: multisite-user-management

Although there just 3 super admins, for some weird reason it says on /wp-admin/network/users.php?role=super that there are 5 and they aren't shown anywhere except those 3 that I have. How can I find those 2 admins? Could it be through the db?